# R is Red color at "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)" in MainActivity.java

Tags: android

When I open My any Project in Android Studio The main problem is in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Here showing error of **`R`**. When I use **Rebuild Project** the Problem is solved, but when I Run the project the same problem is appeared in the run time.

Comment: remove import statemet for R and reimport the R class that is belonging to your project

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- I find that `R` class not found related issues are usually because of errors in the xml resources(layouts, drawables, etc). Fix them and then try running.
- Sync gradle manually: `cmd+shift+a` and search for gradle sync. Fix any errors that may popup.
- Invalidate caches and restart Android Studio.